# Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

When I opened netbeans 6.9.1, It showed me a message box "Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available." I clicked close program button and waited for a solution. But it's still a problem. Can anyone please suggest or help me to fix the problem, thanks.

I use window 7 64bit, jdk 1.6.0_23.

Comment: Sounds like an installation error. I would try re-installing the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I recently fix this issue restart the computer in safe mode and run the installer.

In my case, the problem was caused by a monitor process that was corrupting installation's files while installation process was executed. A [similar bug was reported](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=118074#c4) before:

> The problem is in the monitoring tool called "Logitech Process Monitor" (lvprcsrv.exe).
>   Please make sure that you are not running this or any other processes monitoring tool.

So, running in safe mode will disable process that could interfere in the installation.